# Confidence Level - Could anyone help me figure out where I went wrong?

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I have been working on this practice problem for a while, and worked it out in two ways, and following from inputting the answers in the system, it notified me that the answers for both of them was wrong.

Could anyone help me figure out where I went wrong in my procedure? And help me work it out the correct way?

> The question goes as follows:

[image: Question Description]

> > The first method

[image: Part (a)]

[image: Part(b)]

> > The second method
> >
> > > Part (a)

$$E = \frac{0.2319-0.1270}{2}= 0.05245$$
$$p = 0.2314-0.05245 = 0.17945$$
$$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}} = \sqrt{\frac{0.17945(1-0.17945)}{195}}= 0.0275$$

Therefore, the critical $z$ value is,
$$z = \frac{E}{\sigma} = \frac{0.05245}{0.0275} = 1.9073 \approx 1.91$$

From the standard table,
$$P ( -1.91 < z < 1.91) = 0.9719 $$

**Confidence Level: 97.19%**

> > > Part (b)

Confidence Level computed as:
$$\frac{19}{20}= 0.95$$

From the standard table,
$$P(z < 1.645) = 0.95$$

For a point estimate of proportion here as $p = 0.17945$, the margin of error is,
$$E = z \times \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$$
$$n = \frac{z^2 \times p(1-p)}{E^2}= \frac{1.645^2 \times 0.17945(1-0.17945)}{0.05245^2}= 144.84$$

**Required sample size: 145**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [finite population correction factor](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat415/lesson/6/6.3) for the interval estimate, because the batch has size $N = 2750$ and you are sampling $n = 195$ axles without replacement from that batch.  So a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ asymptotic confidence interval will have the form
$$\hat p \pm z_{\alpha/2}^* \sqrt{\frac{\hat p (1 - \hat p)}{n} \frac{N - n}{N - 1}},$$ where $\hat p$ is the point estimate of the proportion of failed axles, and $z_{\alpha/2}^*$ is the upper $\alpha/2$ quantile of the standard normal distribution, i.e. $\Pr[Z \le z_{\alpha/2}^*] = 1 - \alpha/2$.  In your case, $$\hat p = \frac{0.1270 + 0.2319}{2},$$ hence the margin of error is $$ME = z_{\alpha/2}^* \sqrt{\frac{\hat p (1 - \hat p)}{n} \frac{N - n}{N - 1}} = \frac{0.2319 - 0.1270}{2}$$ and the critical value is $$z_{\alpha/2}^* = \frac{0.2319 - 0.1270}{2} \sqrt{\frac{195}{(0.17945)(1 - 0.17945)} \cdot \frac{2750 - 1}{2750 - 195}}.$$  This gives $1 - \alpha/2 = \Phi(1.97984)$ or $\alpha = 0.0477213$.

For the second part, what they are telling you is that the desired margin of error is $ME = 4\% = 0.04$, and the desired confidence level is $19/20 = 95\%$, corresponding to $\alpha/2 = 0.025$.  If we assume the point estimate from part (a) stays the same, then the required sample size is $$n = \frac{m}{1 + \frac{m-1}{N}}, \quad m = \frac{(z_{\alpha/2}^*)^2 \hat p (1 - \hat p)}{ME^2}.$$  This gives $n = 314$, meaning $314 - 195 = 119$ more axles need to be sampled.

Comment: Thank you so much for your in detail explanation. It was quite concise and easy to understand. What still puzzles me though, is why both answers are still determined to be wrong by the system.

Comment: @Telomere If you have not studied finite population correction, then you should take it out of the calculation, even though this technically leads to an incorrect result.  If you have studied it, then I have no explanation for the system because I have no way to determine what it thinks should be the answer.  Automated homework assignment systems like these are lousy ways to check student proficiency and understanding of mathematics.

Comment: I must agree. I have been feeling discouraged at this practice homework because I am not learning much from it besides the fact that my answers to certain questions are wrong. Anyway, thank you so much for your help. It was very helpful and much appreciate